# How do you use a web.py application in Wordpress?

Tags: python, wordpress, web.py

I have written an application in python to collect data from a javascript form and returned the processed text. It is based entirely off of the code here (but a lot more complex, so I have to use python for this).

https://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/

(note to people who like to edit...please leave this link in place since it shows all the relevant code sections in python and javascript).

I need to use this in wordpress (since that's what runs my site) and I honestly have no idea how to pull this off.  Webpy can run with Apache CGI, but the documentation (http://webpy.org/cookbook/cgi-apache) is only clear if one wants to navigate directly to the python app as its own page.

I'm hoping someone here has expertise in how to embed this all within a Wordpress page/post?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no native way to run Python code inside a WordPress site just like php. In fact, if you are not doing anything unique to Python, I would suggest you to use php, which supports regular expression and can be used in WordPress by installing the plugin "Insert PHP".

If you really want to use Python, then you need an API endpoint where you connect the function to your website. You would have to look into Azure Function App/AWS lambda on which you write a function app to work as a backend. Then whenever someone request your website, your website would do an HTTP request to that API.

Can you explain what exactly you want to do on your website?

Comment: It's very sophisticated NLP processing on user-entered text.

Comment: Take this site(http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/) as an example, you enter a block of text where they give you an analysis of sentiment. They operate it by making an HTTP POST to http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/, where they host the analysis function over.